# Not able to contact elasticsearch on 9200

Tags: elasticsearch

Team,

1. I have installed elastic search service and prerequisites on a local machine. I could see that "service elasticsearch status" shows that service is running.
2. Below logs are dumped to /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log file when service is launched. Ip table service is stopped.
3. I explicitly un commented network.host and port fields to bind to specified ip  and port( 9200), but when i try to contact the machine using 
   `http://address:9200`, nothing shows up, but the webserver is running on this machine and other sites are accessible. Any thoughts?

Log:

```
[2014-05-02 22:24:17,884][INFO ][node                     ] [Sharon Ventura] version[1.1.1], pid[21799], build[f1585f0/2014-04-16T14:27:12Z] 
[2014-05-02 22:24:17,885][INFO ][node                     ] [Sharon Ventura] initializing ... 
[2014-05-02 22:24:17,892][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Sharon Ventura] loaded [], sites [head] 
[2014-05-02 22:24:22,288][INFO ][node                     ] [Sharon Ventura] initialized 
[2014-05-02 22:24:22,288][INFO ][node                     ] [Sharon Ventura] starting ... 
[2014-05-02 22:24:22,394][INFO ][transport                ] [Sharon Ventura] bound_address {inet[/10.147.38.151:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/<ip-address>:9300]} 
[2014-05-02 22:24:25,449][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Sharon Ventura] new_master [Sharon Ventura][GYPgQG0qSniSd36gP7ErdA][inet[/<ip-address>:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master) 
[2014-05-02 22:24:25,611][INFO ][discovery                ] [Sharon Ventura] elasticsearch/GYPgQG0qSniSd36gP7ErdA 
[2014-05-02 22:24:25,714][INFO ][http                     ] [Sharon Ventura] bound_address {inet[/10.147.38.151:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/<ip-address>:9200]} 
[2014-05-02 22:24:25,759][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Sharon Ventura] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state 
[2014-05-02 22:24:25,760][INFO ][node                     ] [Sharon Ventura] started
```

Thanks! 
Santhosh

Comment: Can you indent your log correctly so it can be user readable

Comment: Can you also add the relevant portions of the elasticsearch.yml file where you made modifications.

Comment: what is the message error when you try to contact elasticsearch?

Comment: Elasticsearch will out of the box default to port `:9200` so you shouldn't necessarily need to uncomment this within the `.yml` file unless you are going to change the port no, the same applies for network address, it will default to localhost, machines IP.

Comment: have you configurate a proxy on your OS, by the way on which OS are you using ? Sometime when things aren't configurate usually you webrequest again localhost are asked to the proxy and this is why it's not working. If your using curl, in this case, try --noproxy localhost !

Comment: I didn't modified anything in yml file initially. AS such i couldn't access it, i specified the ip address and port host configuration in elasticsearch yml file, restarted service. IP tables service is stopped on this machine, i tried doing telnet to port 9200 and it works, service for elastic search says its running. When contacted from browser using the mentioned url,nothing shows up and the above logs are the one dumped. When trying to access elastic search node from code, iam getting a transport error. Why iam not seeing it from browser as mentioned on site?

Comment: If telnet works but not the browser than i guess its a proxy error. Does work curl too? Regarding the transport error please post a complete stacktrace and, if possible, your client code.

Answer (score 2):

I got the issue fixed, its the elasticsearch.yml file configuration which has the issue, the ip address was set to the natted ipaddress and its working.

One more Question:  Iam using python elasticsearch package, here iam doing an index using es.index() and wanted to search for few records post the index, using its search() function, any specific examples of how to use search function for getting records between two dates for all files which are indexed?

Comment: Please post additional questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

In your log you have an ip so you don't run it on localhost. 
Check the firewall and actually that the port 9200 is accessible to you.

If you ssh and port forward into that server/computer can you access elasticsearch? If you cannot access it locally on that server, then it should something other than the port.

Give us some more details about your systems/servers to help you.

Comment: Please see the comments i added to the question above. It has all answers to your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, confirm your firewall is not blocking the port,
You can also disable the firewall to confirm if thats the issue

```
sudo ufw disable
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```